# In Nested Grid Layouts with flexible rows, why do I need two `overflow:auto` for scrollbars

Tags: html, css, css-grid

While designing grids, there is a peculiarity I've observed which I can't explain, or find a clear-cut reason for in the grid spec. Consider a layout with nested grids, with the parent grid having a **row with height defined in `fr` units**. This flexible-sized row contains the child grid which **contains one row with a percent-based height** (say `100%`). This row contains a `content` cell which can have a lot of content which can overflow, thus we need to **show scrollbar for this `content` cell**.

For the `content` cell to have a scrollbar, I find myself needing to add the `overflow: auto` property not just to the content cell, but also to the `child-grid` cell (`content` div's parent). Nothing else works to give me a scrollable div.

Some more things I've tried:
1. setting `height: 100%` on the content cell doesn't work. I think it's probably because the parent-grid's row is `fr` sized, so the height is computed dynamically (somewhat like height: auto), thus any child div can't use percent-based heights.
2. setting the `max-height` property on the `child-grid`. It feels logically right, it would simply calculate the height from the parent grid and not overflow that. But even this doesn't work.

I made this small example to illustrate what I mean to say:

https://codepen.io/kumarharsh/pen/qQmwQB

```css
.parent-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #f00;
}
.child-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
}
.content {
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: auto;
}
.no-overflow-auto {
  overflow: initial;
}
.height-100 {
  height: 100%;
}
.max-height-100 {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.data {
  padding: 1em;
}
p {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-grid">
  <div class="child-grid">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="data">A</div><div class="data">A</div><div class="data">A</div><div class="data">A</div><div class="data">A</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>What I'm trying to achieve. All lorem ipsum should be bound by the grey box and red border</p>

<div class="parent-grid">
  <div class="child-grid">
    <div class="content no-overflow-auto">
      <div class="data">A</div><div class="data">A</div><div class="data">A</div><div class="data">A</div><div class="data">A</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>lorem ipsum exceeds the grey box but not the border (content - overflow:initial)</p>

<div class="parent-grid">
  <div class="child-grid no-overflow-auto">
    <div class="content"><div class="data">A</div><div class="data">A</div><div class="data">A</div><div class="data">A</div><div class="data">A</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>lorem ipsum exceeds the grey box and red border (child-grid - overflow:initial)</p>

<div class="parent-grid">
  <div class="child-grid no-overflow-auto max-height-100">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="data">A</div><div class="data">A</div><div class="data">A</div><div class="data">A</div><div class="data">A</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Child-grid - max-height:100%</p>

<div class="parent-grid">
  <div class="child-grid no-overflow-auto max-height-100">
    <div class="content height-100">
      <div class="data">A</div><div class="data">A</div><div class="data">A</div><div class="data">A</div><div class="data">A</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Content - height:100%</p>
```

All the grids are exactly the same, but the second grid doesn't have an `overflow:auto` applied to the content cell, the third one doesn't have an `overflow:auto` on the child-grid, the fourth one has `height:100%` applied to the `content` div and last one has `max-height:100%` applied to the `child-grid`.

So it feels like the `overflow:auto` of the child-grid is just there to force-set a definite height for the `content` div so that scrollbars appear. But this is just a conjecture.

Can someone explain why it's necessary to specify `overflow:auto` on both the `child-grid` and `content` in such a layout?

Comment: A grid item cannot be smaller than its content, by default (`min-height: auto`). With `overflow: auto` (or `min-height: 0`), that default is overridden. Also `1fr` is equivalent to `minmax(auto, 1fr)` (*min* is set to content length). When that becomes a problem, instead of `1fr`, use `minmax(0, 1fr)`.

Comment: Thanks for the linked duplicates which link to the W3C discussions on this.